# Bootstrap div wider than phone width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have these bootstrap divs that are wider than a phone's width (412px). Why?
What can I do so that the divs would be as wide as the phone's width?

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: red">
        1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: yellow">
        1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: blue">
        1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with these divs. What is your viewport meta tag set to? Any other CSS affecting width, padding, margins, etc?

Comment: Have you add the viewport meta tag ? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: this is what I have. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;" /> Adding shrink-to-fit=no doesn't help :(

Comment: Try to add initial-scale

Comment: I've put your exact <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"> Still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing class `container` as parent from bootstrap, so use this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: red">
      1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: yellow">
      1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: blue">
      1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Given your link, the issue is the `min-width:600px` in `body` that you have in your CSS file

Comment: It is the same with container. Now I also have some padding, from the container https://media.giphy.com/media/3oKIPjDKUXYfOVjWaQ/giphy.gif

Comment: show your full code please, from `<!DOCTYPE html>` to end

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y149vs33/ damn on jsfiddle it seems to work. Maybe I have some custom hidden css, I will check :(

Comment: if you gave us a link,  we might help you out debugging it

Comment: @Cătălin Rădoi Add css to body may helps to solve it

Comment: @dippas here's the link http://ihavenotv.com/test It's a (free) documentaries website :P